# How to pass GET parameters to next controller action in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 4.2 app I have an `index` action that lists all the user's invoices, filtered by search parameters in the URL:

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @invoices = current_user.invoices.search(params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        @title = "Invoices"
        ...
      end
      format.csv do
        headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=\"#{invoices_filename}.csv\""
      end
      format.xls do
        headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=\"#{invoices_filename}.xls\""
      end
    end
  end

  ...

end
```

This works nicely. The user can filter his invoices by various parameters and the listed invoices adjust accordingly.

The problems start when the user wants to download these exact invoices in XLS or CSV format. I have a link for that on `index.html.erb`:

```
<%= link_to "Download invoices", invoices_path(:format => "xls") %>
```

However, it downloads all the invoices, not just the ones the user filtered out previously.

Is there a way to pass the search params on to the next action or maybe a more elegant solution all together?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to send the params along with the `format`

This will do the trick:

```
<%= link_to "Download invoices", invoices_path(params.merge(format: :xls)) %>
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you!